# Page Reload while clicking on the href link

Tags: javascript, html

I have a web application in which index.jsp is a welcome page.  Index.jsp contains the UI code . And i have  multiple html files which has the same href link . My problem is whenever I click on the link the UI is reloaded. So when the url is same, the UI should be maintained and the page should not be reloaded.

I am new to web application development . Please help me on this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<div id="myform_sample1">
<a href="http://localhost:8080/app/index.jsp?file=filepath" target="http://localhost:8080/app/index.jsp?file=filepath">sample1<br>
</a>
</div>
<div id="myform_sample2">
<a href="http://localhost:8080/app/index.jsp?file=filepath" target="http://localhost:8080/app/index.jsp?file=filepath">sample2<br>
</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you tried ajax post ?

Comment: Post your code in order to see where's the problem. maybe you are wrong in the url inserted inside the href.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  cache: false,
  success: function(html){
    $("#results").append(html);
  }
});
```

on a click event you can transfer values and get back through ajax without reloading ur UI

Comment: I didn't notice the jQuery tag on the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking for jQuery:[load](http://api.jquery.com/load/), [get](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/), [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)